# Laravel Phpunit, AssertJsonFragment not working as expected

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-8

I've done this thousands of times on past projects, but I feel since moving to laravel 8 on our latest application something has changed.

I used to be able to do something as simple as:

```
$response = $this->post('/api/team', []);
$response->assertJsonFragment([
    "The team name field is required."
]);
```

However when running the test I get the following error:

```
1) Tests\Feature\Controllers\Team\CreateTest::teamNameRequired
Unable to find JSON fragment: 

[["The team name field is required."]]

within

[["{\"team_name\":[\"The team name field is required.\"]}"]].
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

I've tried swapping to `assertJson` and a couple others but ideally this is how I'd like to assert, I also could create a separate function or use some other helpers but I want to assert not just that there has been a validation error, but a specific one.

I'm using the standard laravel validator and response object for context:

```
$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), [
            'name' => 'required|string|between:2,100'
        ]);

        if($validator->fails()){
            return response()->json($validator->errors()->toJson(), 400);
        }
```

Comment: I think you want to use this one: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-tests#assert-json-validation-errors

Comment: So interestingly, if I use that with the key of 'team_name', or the error itself I still get a failure of not found in response.

Comment: I've cracked it, it's because I have `toJson()` inside my response json function.

Answer (score -1):

This was caused because I was json encoding the errors twice.

Within my controller the following if statement should have been used:

```
if($validator->fails()){
    return response()->json($validator->errors(), 400);
}
```